# Difference between template and yaml file in DevOps

Tags: variables, azure-devops, parameters, devops

I just started reading about DevOps on Microsoft site and I come across these 2 files. I'm confused about the process needing 2 files, with YAML using variable and template using parameter...At moment, I'm still unclear they have to separate between variable and parameter?

Comment: Hi user234568; what kind of template are you talking about? Like these [pipeline templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops), or something different?

Answer (score 1):

They are talking about ARM Templates. While you can have Parent/Child Templates it's more complex and I've never seen an example that split Variables and Parameters to different files.

To clear up the confusion [ARM Templates have 5 main parts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/syntax):

**Variables** things you know at design time like VNet address.

**Parameters** things you know at runtime and don't want stored in the template's (YAML format) script such as Usernames and Passwords.

**Functions** things you compute in your template.

**Resources** things you are provisioning.

**Outputs** things you can reuse, such as a Url result of provisioning a Azure Web App.